# Select record WHERE id not contain in the table from MySQL

Tags: mysql

i need help...I have three tables in MySQL: `price_table`, `item_table`, and `tariff_table` with record:

Record in `item_table`:

```
id_item | name_item
1       | Item A    
2       | Item B    
3       | Item C    
4       | Item D    
5       | Item E
```

Record in `tariff_table`:

```
id_tariff | name_tariff
1         | normal    
2         | promo
```

Record in `price_table`:

```
id_price | id_item | id_tarif
1        | 1       | 1
2        | 2       | 1
3        | 3       | 1
4        | 4       | 1
5        | 5       | 1
6        | 1       | 2
7        | 2       | 2
```

I want select the `id_item` that do not have `id_tariff = 2`.

Comment: What have you tried so far? This is about the most basic SQL query there is, I suspect some simple searches will turn up what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do Self join.

[**SQLFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4ba59/4)

Here is the output :
[image]

```
SELECT T.id_price,item_table.name_item
FROM
price_table T
INNER JOIN item_table ON T.id_item = item_table.id_item
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT T1.*
FROM
price_table T1
INNER JOIN price_table T2 ON T1.`id_item`= T2.`id_item` AND T1.`id_tarif` <> T2.`id_tarif`) Dup ON T.`id_item` = Dup.`id_item`
WHERE Dup.`id_item` IS NULL
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT P.id_item, I.name_item
FROM price_table P
INNER JOIN tariff_table T ON T.id_tariff = p. id_tariff
INNER JOIN item_table I on I.id_item = p.id_item
WHERE
  P.id_tariff != 2
  AND p.id_item NOT IN 
   (SELECT id_item FROM price_table WHERE id_tariff = 2)
```

Comment: I try your trick above, but MySQL return an empty result, thanks

Comment: OK.....appenmd to my previous answer

AND p.id_item NOT IN (SELECT id_item FROM price_table WHERE id_tariff = 2)